# Set err in couchbase

Tags: go, couchbase

It returns EOF when I use go-couchbase to set data into couchbse.

```
cl, err := gocb.Connect("http://administrator:passwd@127.0.0.1:8091")
...
pool, err := cl.GetPool("default")
...
bucket, err := pool.GetBucket("default")
...
err = bucket.Set("aaa",0,"bbb")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Set error ", err.Error())
}
bucket.Close()
```

And then I check the log file named memcached.log, the err info is " not aware of extended error code (no bucket)".

If there is no bucket named default , GetBucket will return the err "No bucket named default".

I don't know why this happens.

Comment: Is there a "default" bucket or not? If not, you'll need to create one. If you are using a different name, you'll need to change `GetBucket` to whatever the name of the bucket is.

Comment: @MatthewGroves Sorry,I haven't seen your reply before.I have created a "default" bucket. The error info is returned by function "Set", not GetBucket. If GetBucket returns err, the fucntion will exit directly without doing set operation.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but is there any reason why you're using an unofficial Go SDK for Couchbase? You'd have a much easier time with the official found at https://github.com/couchbase/gocb

Comment: I have tried for both SDK. But there is something wrong when I use official SDK to bulk insert a large amount of data.I'm try to find some other way to solve this problem.     [https://issues.couchbase.com/projects/GOCBC/issues/GOCBC-231](https://issues.couchbase.com/projects/GOCBC/issues/GOCBC-231)